# EF Code First: IValidatable Object not validating

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have an object in a simple test scenario that uses EF Code First and implements IValidatableObject. There's some very simple logic that adds a validation error and returns it back. There are also other validations on the object.

However, when saving the object - while the attribute based validations work - the IValidatableObject interface never seems to fire. Debugger doesn't step into it and the error never shows up with calling SaveChanges() or GetValidationErrors().

```
public class Customer : IValidatableObject {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[StringLength(50)]
[DisplayName("First Name")]

public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("Last Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string Company { get; set; }

[StringLength(200)]
public string Email { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Credit Limit")]
public decimal CreditLimit { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Entered On")]
public DateTime? Entered { get; set; }


public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set;  }


public Customer()
{
    Entered = DateTime.Now;
    CreditLimit = 1000.00M;

    Addresses = new List<Address>();
}

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    // add an error ALWAYS for testing - it doesn't show up
    // and the debugger never hits this code
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Validate Added message",new [] { "Company" }));

    return results;
}
```

When I now try to add a customer and check for validation errors:

```
public void AddNewCustomer()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();  

    context.Customers.Add(customer);

    customer.LastName = "Strahl";
    customer.FirstName = "Rick";
    customer.Entered = DateTime.Now;
    //customer.Company = "West Wind"; // missing causes val error

    var errorEntries = context.GetValidationErrors();
}
```

I get ONE validation error for the company, but nothing from the IValidatableObject which should ALWAYS fail.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quote from [Jeff Handley's Blog Post on Validation Objects and Properties with Validator](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx):

> When validating an object, the
>   following process is applied in
>   Validator.ValidateObject:
>
> 1. Validate property-level attributes
> 2. *If any validators are invalid, abort validation returning the
>      failure(s)*
> 3. Validate the object-level attributes
> 4. *If any validators are invalid, abort validation returning the
>      failure(s)*
> 5. If on the desktop framework and the object implements
>      IValidatableObject, then call its
>      Validate method and return any
>      failure(s)

This indicates that what you are attempting to do won't work out-of-the-box because the validation will abort at step #2.

Comment: Yup that's it. If there are no other validation errors the IValidatableObject code fires. Not happy about this behavior though - it's sucky to not show the users ALL errors that apply.